# How to do a wild card search across few git repositories in GitHub

Tags: github

How to do a wild card search across few git repositories in GitHub.

```
org:company https://apps.apple.com repo:*health*
```

In the above scenario I am trying to search `https://apps.apple.com` in my company repo `org:company` across git repositories which contain a name of `health`. This is not working as expected, not sure how to perform a wildcard search